# Azure DevOps Pipeline: Download publish artifact (webapp.zip) to specific server or local directory of PC

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I have created a pipeline in Azure DevOps and wanted to download the publish artifact to a server, each time I am running the pipeline I can see the Published zip file in Drop folder on Azure but I am not getting any way to download the zip on local directory (specifically I want to download webapp.zip file in a folder on a specific server).

Please suggest which task I need to add and where I can add the server details for downloading the zip file.

Answer (score 1):

> Please suggest which task I need to add and where I can add the server details for downloading the zip file.

Based on your requirement, you could use the [Download Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) or [Download Pipeline Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops).

**Depending on what task you use to publish artifacts：**

Publish build artifacts task -> Download Build Artifacts task

Publish pipeline artifacts task -> Download Pipeline Artifacts task

You could define the path(**Destination directory**) on your local machine in the task, then the zip file will be downloaded to local machine.

[image]

**Note:** Since you need to download the file to local machine or server, you need to run the pipeline on [Self-Hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install).